# Subsequent tests fail in Django after first tests succeeds

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tdd

When using the following code, only the second testcase will pass (since it's executed first) and the rest will fail.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Application(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=255)
```

**test.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase

from application.models import Application


class ApplicationTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        testApplication = Application(
            title="Application Title",
            description="Application Description",
            url="http://www.application-url.com"
        )
        testApplication.save()

    def test_application_has_title(self):
        application = Application.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.assertEqual(application.title, "Application Title")

    def test_application_has_description(self):
        application = Application.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.assertEqual(application.description, "Application Description")

    def test_application_has_url(self):
        application = Application.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.assertEqual(application.url, "http://www.application-url.com")
```

To me it seems that the object is removed from the DB after the first test, but that shouldn't happen. I'm quite new to Django, so any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, by design, each test is designed to run independently and so the DB gets reinitialized after each test; I don't know if there's an issue where some DB is using a different PK each time but in either case, I'd suggest swapping .get(pk=1) with .all()[0]

Comment: Doing this seems to make the first two tests work but the final test, test_application_has_url(), still fails.

"DoesNotExist: Application matching query does not exist."

Comment: if you comment out the first two tests (or just rename so they don't start with test), does the 3rd work?

Answer (score 0):

it could be that `testApplication` doesn't have the pk of 1, you could try the following:

```
class ApplicationTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.testApplication = Application.objects.create(
            title="Application Title",
            description="Application Description",
            url="http://www.application-url.com"
        )

    def test_application_has_url(self):
        application = Application.objects.get(pk=self.testApplication.id)
        self.assertEqual(application.url, "http://www.application-url.com")
```